# Get Values From NSArray and add it to NSDictionary

Tags: ipad, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have `NSArray` inside the array I have many Dictionaries. I want all those dictionary value into single dictionary

```
jewels array (
    {
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
},
    {
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
    noseAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f84e40>";
},
    {
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
    neckAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7d8c0>";
    noseAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f84e40>";
}
```

)

I want output like this

```
    {
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
    noseAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f84e40>";
    headAccObi = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7da00>";
    neckAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f7d8c0>";
    noseAccObj = "<AccessoriesObject: 0x7f84e40>";
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create exactly the structure you've described because you have the same key used multiple times.  Adding an object with `setObject:forKey:` will replace an existing object if the key is duplicated.  You would need to store an array of objects in your dictionary for each key such as `headAccObi` where there are repeats.